# Check if a string contains a number, while allowing multiple decimal points?

Tags: php

This is to test version numbers. They need to contain only numbers, but can have multiple decimal points.

For example:

```
$a = '1.2.3';
```

is_numeric($a) returns false, and floatval($a) strips out the extra decimal sections, without returning a useful answer to the test.

Is there any PHP function that would do this?

Comment: Or, why not just compare them as strings?

Comment: @Mattt: I won't have a specific value to compare it to. I just need to know if a single string contains purely a number, while allowing multiple decimal points.

Comment: If this is for subsequent version comparison, why not use [version_compare()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)

Comment: @MarkBaker: I don't need to compare two values, just test one for the aforementioned constraints. Interesting function though, it might be useful down the line. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `preg_match()`:

```
if(preg_match('~^([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*)$~', $string)) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

The regex pattern matches from the begin `^` to the end `$` of the string and checks if it begins with a number and then contains only numbers - optionally separated by single dots - and ends with a number again.

Comment: When I started brainstorming explode() and loops to handle this, I didn't even consider the need to check for trailing periods or multiple subsequent periods, and it would've messed me up later. This is perfect, thanks :)

Comment: @equazcion You are welcome. :) Yes, there are many cases where `explode()` or some other non-regex function is preferred over preg_* functions and you are encouraged to think about this every time you search for the perfect solution. I also thought about it before giving the `preg_` answer. But in this case a regex is perfect! (imo)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`strcspn`](http://php.net/strcspn) function:

```
$q='1.2.3';

if (strcspn($q, '0123456789') != strlen($q))
  echo "true";
else
  echo "false";
```